# C++ desktop applications framework

Tags: c++

I am not new to c++,but i have not found a c++ desktop applications framework.I have found one and it seems to complex.Are there other frameworks available for c++ out there?.

Comment: I am new around,plus i have accepted all the last answers to my questions.

Comment: @Undgerman: No, you're here for more than a month, and obviously haven't even bothered to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) yet. Schlecht.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various choices when it comes to c++ Desktop app frameworks, 
it mainy depends on your skills and on the plattform you want the app to run.

Two Opensource Frameworks that are plattform independent, I have used so far are

The [QT-Framework](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) from trolltech now nokia and [wxWidgets](http://qt.nokia.com/products/)
if you need something in the multimedia area have a look at [openframeworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/)

Comment: true
but openframeworks still better in this area and also easyer to start with

Answer (score 5):

Qt - forever! It is mature and cross-platform.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)

Comment: qt licensing is complex. read more about it, before considering. https://www1.qt.io/licensing-comparison/

Answer (score 3):

There's [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org) and [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/), both Open Source and free. Qt became very popular recently.

Also, you might want to look at [C++ Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder), which allows you to build C++ applications in a VB-like way using a component framework built in Delphi. (That's a commercial one. They used to have a free version, but I don't know whether that still exists.)

Answer (score 2):

A great framework is [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)).